# How to create a tree in python?

Tags: python

I have a folder of 100 html files that I am trying to create a tree out of name page1 - page100. Each page has a hyperlink in it that opens up another page. I am trying to get it to where the program reads the root node(page1.html) reads its hyperlinks and creates children based off those links, and then repeats this for  the rest of the nodes until the tree is complete. What is the best way to go about this using the hyperlinks? Here is my code so far.

```
    import os
from math import* 
from os.path import isfile, join

entries = os.listdir("C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1") #This reads the directory

onlyfiles = [f for f in entries if isfile(join("C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1", f))] #This took all the webpages in the directory and put them into a list.

print(onlyfiles)

web = open("C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1" + "/" + onlyfiles[0]) # This will tell us if the webpage is readable or not

print(web.readable()) # This tells if the file is readable 

print(web.readlines()) #This reads the content of the file

web.close()
```

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework". And more generally, please read [ask].

Comment: Why to use tree? If every page has exactly one link out, array or linked list is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.walk to iterate over all subdirectories:

```py
import os
path = 'C:/Users/deonh/Downloads/intranets/intranet1'
entries = []
onlyfiles = []
for directory, _, files in os.walk(path):  # second value would be subdirectries but we don't need them because we iterate over all directories
    entries.append(directory)
    for file in files:
        onlyfiles.append('{}/{}'.format(directory, file))  # 

if os.access(onlyfiles[0], os.R_OK):  # This will tell us if the webpage is readable or not
    with open(onlyfiles[0]) as file:  # file is closing automatically
        print(file.readlines())

print(onlyfiles[0], os.R_OK)  # This tells if the file is readable
print(onlyfiles)  # This reads the content of the file
```

Please ask if something is unclear.